# Converting stack() call from v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've had a modified version of Mike Bostock's animated stack ([seen here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4679202)) working for awhile now.  On the advice of others here I've been trying to convert all of my D3 version 3 charts to version 4, so everything is compatible moving forward.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out why this code segment won't compile.  It's throwing the "Uncaught TypeError".  Which I've been told has to do with the newer version wanting an array passed to stack().

```
var stack = d3.stack()
    .values(data, function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .out(function(d, y0) { d.valueOffset = y0; });
```

How should this be done correctly under D3 version 4?

Edit: I also found [this link to a support request on github](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/93), but it seems no one over there could simply explain how to convert this chart either.

Comment: the v4 stack function expects csv-like data. You'll have to change your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 v4 `d3.stack()` constructor don't have `values`, `x`, `y` and `out` chaining methods. It's syntax for 3rd version. Check docs [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stack). Look at [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mjfoster83/7c9bdfd714ab2f2e39dd5c09057a55a0) of stacked bar chart. Note, as `d3.stack` uses in this example:

```
...
  g.append("g")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
   .enter().append("g")
...
```

Update:
I rewrote "bl.ocks" by Mike Bostock mentioned in the question to the d3 v4. Look at this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/levvsha/vrbq7ebz/

Comment: So you're saying that I simply can't do things that way with the stack method in the new version?  I love D3 but it's extremely frustrating that the new version is not logically compatible with version 3.

Comment: @Keith Unfortunately, It's true. Some parts of the D3 were rewritten in the fourth version. I have some experience with upgrading component from the third version to fourth. I rewrote "bl.ocks" which you mentioned to the fourth version and updated answer, look at this - https://jsfiddle.net/levvsha/vrbq7ebz/ . 
I hope this helps you rewrite your component.

Comment: It works! That was great of you to do Mikhail, really appreciate the live example.